How to perform update in a nested array element in spring data monogo
I am trying to create a Expense tracker application using SpringBoot, MonogDB and ReactJS
I have a collection called "userexpense" which each record has three fields "id","email" and "expenses"
{
  "id":"123",
  "email":"example@gmail.com",
  "expenses":[
     {
       "taskid": "xyz",
       "amount": "90",
       "description": "vada pav",
       "category": "food"
     },
     {
       "taskid": "qpr",
       "amount": "900",
       "description": "train",
       "category": "transport"
     }
  ]
}

"expenses" is an array of objects which holds expenses of individual users.
I want to perform update operation on element of expenses array.
updates like changing the amount and description of a particular expense based its taskid.
How can i do this?
github repo:
https://github.com/Sumit-Rodge/spring-boot-expense-api
This is what i have tried
Query query = new Query();
Criteria criteria1 = Criteria.where("id").is(id);
Criteria criteria2 = Criteria.where("expenses").elemMatch(Criteria.where("id").is(taskid));
query.addCriteria(new Criteria().andOperator(criteria1, criteria2));

Update update = new Update().pull("Expenses" , new BasicDBObject("id",taskid));
mongoTemplate.update(query,update,UserExpense.class);

found the answer.
@PutMapping("updateexpense/{id}/{taskid}")
    public void updateExpense(@PathVariable String id,@PathVariable String taskid) {
        mongoTemplate.updateFirst(
                Query.query(Criteria.where("_id").is(id).and("expenses._id").is(taskid)),
                new Update().set("expenses.$.description", "temp")
                        .set("expenses.$.amount", "tem[")
                        .set("expenses.$.category", "temp"),
                UserExpense.class
        );
    }


Post your "found the answer" part as an answer to your own question; don't add it to the question.
